# JavaScript bracket notation equivalent in Scala?

Tags: scala

JavaScript has bracket notation for objects that allows you to access properties using variables like so:

```
let x = {name : 'John', age: 21};
let y = 'age'
console.log(x[y])
//21
```

Is there an equivalent to this for accessing properties in class objects (get all variables in a class instance) in Scala 2?

Comment: I am unable to suggest edits but your example does not correspond to the comment you wrote on someone's (now) deleted answer. Perhaps, rephrase your question better ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: You may do this using reflection but note that would be unsafe, insecure, slow, and non-portable. In general, changing a language means changing mindest not just syntax and between **Javascript** and **Scala** that difference is way bigger. These kinds of things are usually considered a code smell in the language and you may want to learn new techniques to avoid this kind of dynamic access.

Comment: JavaScript's objects are not class objects. They are simple tables with keys being string already, which is similar to hashmap/hashtable in other languages. Equitting this to class objects in Scala is a false equivalance.

Answer (score 1):

Since all case classes extend from [`Product`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/scala/Product.html) I wonder if you can call its method `productElement(1)` for getting its value. I mean using the index of the desired field for getting its value.

```
case class MyClass(cat: String, dogNum: Int )

val myClass = MyClass("white cat", 2)

println(myClass.productElement(1)) // prints 2
println(myClass.productElement(0)) // prints white cat
```

also, using pattern matching:

```
myClass match {
  
 case MyClass(catField, dogNumField) => 
  println(catField)  // prints white cat
  println(dogNumField) //prints 2
  
}
```

as yet another way for achieving what might be looking for:

```
myClass.productIterator.foreach(member => println(member))
```

**Update**

"Since Scala 2.13 you can also retrieve the names of the attributes of a [Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Product.html)." – Gaël J

So you can write:

```
val productSize = myClass.productArity


for (elementNum <- 0 to productSize-1){
   
   println(myClass.productElementName(elementNum) + ": " + myClass.productElement(elementNum))

}
```

which prints:

```
cat: white cat
dogNum: 2
```

Comment: Since Scala 2.13 you can also retrieve the names of the attributes of a `Product`.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks, I updated the answer to include this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this can be done with Java's Reflection API. I haven't tried it myself yet so you might need to play with it to find the right implementation.

These might help:

- https://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html